# What was dumped into {{ns:6}}?

Tags: mediawiki

I know `File:` &  `Image:` were consolidated into `{{ns:6}}` completely, did this also absorb `Media:` or does that still have a separate purpose?  I'm working on generalizing all of one wikis `MediaWiki:` & `Template:` pages for importing to the new sister wiki and wanted to make as many generalizations with [AWB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aAutoWikiBowser) as I can before I export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the *Virtual namespaces* section of the *Wikipedia:Namespace* page on the English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aMedia_namespace#Virtual_namespaces).

Basically, the `Media:` namespace doesn't actually exist, it's just used for linking.